# collection list to find what is the difference in two lists python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code, To compare two list and I have used collections since i am ok if elements positions are differ. The script  checks  list2 has all elements that contains in list1.   This is working fine. Now I need help what is missing or what is difference when compare list1 with list2.

```
list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777']
list2 = ['ab', 'cd','600', '4','a=7777','b=7777']
if collections.Counter(list1) != collections.Counter(list):
   print "something not matching  or missing list1 with list2"
   print "help me what is missing or what different values between list1 and list2"
```

Expected output:

```
   if 
   list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777']
   list2 = ['ab', 'cd','600', '4','a=7777','b=7777']

   Expected output:
   Do Not print anything.


   elif
   list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777']
   list2 = ['ab', 'cd','600', '4','a=7777','b=77']
   Expected output:
   print "MisMatch"
   print "In list2 b=7777 should contain"

   elif
   list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777']
   list2 = ['ab', 'cd','600','a=7777','b=7777']
   Expected output:
   print "MisMatch"
   print "In list2 4 is missing"
```

Comment: you should use python's `set` type for this. It supports difference, union, intersection, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for a `set`:

```
>>> list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777']
>>> list2 = ['ab', 'cd','600', '4','a=7777','b=77']
>>> set(list1) - set(list2))
{'b=7777'}
```

Note that a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is an:

> Unordered collection of unique elements

so it will not tell you *how many* elements are missing from a list, just which ones are missing.

For example:

```
>>> list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777', 'b=7777']
>>> list2 = ['ab', 'cd','600', '4','a=7777','b=77']
>>> set(list1) - set(list2)
{'b=7777'}
```

Will still only output one element, although there are 2 of them in your first list.

If you want to keep track of these duplicates, check out [@John La Rooy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143863/3483203).

Comment: set operators to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not having duplicates, `set` is the way to go. But it's worth knowing that you can do a similar "math" with `Counter`s

```
>>> list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777']
>>> list2 = ['ab', 'cd','600', '4','a=7777','b=77']
>>> c1 = Counter(list1)
>>> c2 = Counter(list2)
>>> print(c1 - c2)
Counter({'b=7777': 1})
>>> print(c2 - c1)
Counter({'b=77': 1})
```

Answer (score -1):

> list1 =  ['ab','cd','600','4','a=7777','b=7777']
>      list2 =  ['ab', 'cd','600', '4','a=7777','b=77']
>
> > (set(list1).difference(list2))
> >
> > output:
> >
> > set(['b=7777'])